# jquery val() only taking the value of first row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a situation here , where i have a form in which i have some similar rows and when i submit the form , i want the quantity value to be displayed which was initial , it is returning the initial value of **only first row** , i know it will do so , but not sure of the solution

html code :

```
    <form class="editcart" method="post" action="">  

       <input type="text" class="pid" name="pid" value="${product.pid}" hidden/>
           <input type="text" class="spid" name="spid" value="${product.sub_pid}" hidden/>
           <input type="text" class="cartid" name="cartid" value="${product.cart_id}" hidden/>
           <input type="text" class="quantity" name="quantity" value="20" readonly="readOnly"/>
           <input type="button" value="Edit" class="enable"/>
           <input type="submit" value="Save" class="save" hidden/>

       <input type="text" class="pid" name="pid" value="${product.pid}" hidden/>
           <input type="text" class="spid" name="spid" value="${product.sub_pid}" hidden/>
           <input type="text" class="cartid" name="cartid" value="${product.cart_id}" hidden/>
           <input type="text" class="quantity" name="quantity" value="5" readonly="readOnly"/>
           <input type="button" value="Edit" class="enable"/>
           <input type="submit" value="Save" class="save" hidden/>

       <input type="text" class="pid" name="pid" value="${product.pid}" hidden/>
           <input type="text" class="spid" name="spid" value="${product.sub_pid}" hidden/>
           <input type="text" class="cartid" name="cartid" value="${product.cart_id}" hidden/>
           <input type="text" class="quantity" name="quantity" value="4" readonly="readOnly"/>
           <input type="button" value="Edit" class="enable"/>
           <input type="submit" value="Save" class="save" hidden/>
    </form>
```

and jquery code is :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var init = $('.quantity',this).val();

  $('.enable').click(function(){         
    $(this).prev('.quantity').prop('readOnly',false); 
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).next('.save').fadeIn();
  });

     $('.editcart').submit(function() {

           var quant = $('.quantity',this).val();  
           var pid = $('.pid',this).val();
           var spid = $('.spid',this).val(); 
           var cartid = $('.cartid',this).val();

    alert("the init value is : "+init);
      return false;

         });

 });
```

[**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rdb43e8w/1/)

Comment: it's because when you try to submit you are selecting the all three **save** button so that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:-

```
 var init =0;
 $('.quantity',this).each(function(){
   init+=parseInt($(this).val());    
});
```

Since you want the value of clicked row use this code:-

```
 $('.save').click(function(){
    init=$(this).prev().prev('.quantity').val();
 });
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rdb43e8w/2/)

[Demo 1](https://jsfiddle.net/rdb43e8w/3)

Comment: it is either taking cumulative value or only the last value if i remove the addition , i only want the value of the specific row which i click

Comment: @amolsingh happy to help you :)